# How can I reverse linked list starting from certain key to the end? (python3)

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, key, reverse

I'm trying to construct a method in python to reverse a singly linked list starting from a certain key to the end. I understood how to reverse the whole linked list, but I can't code

`def reverse(self, key)`

- key is not the node but value.

Comment: Why don't you traverse to the end of the list and start reversing the list and stop when you get to the node with a specific value?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer would be to first initialize a doubly linked list, but we'll mimic its use case in this scenario and create a temporary "previous" node as we walk through.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert(self, key):
        node = Node(key)
        if self.tail:
            self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail = self.head = node

    def reverse(self, key):
        first = []
        prev = None
        current, self.head, self.tail = self.head, self.tail, self.head
        while current:
            if current.value == key:
                first.append(current)

            current.next, current, prev = prev, current.next, current
        return first

    def list_nodes(self):
        res = []
        current = self.head
        while current:
            res.append(current.value)
            current = current.next
        return res


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.next = None
        self.value = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = LinkedList()
    for i in range(100):
        lst.insert(i)
    res1 = lst.list_nodes()
    rev = lst.reverse(55)
    res2 = lst.list_nodes()
```

The Output would be:

```
res1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
res2 = [99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
rev = [<__main__.Node object at 0x00000271B63241C0>]  # A Node object at some location
```

This will reverse and search for that key and return it in a list and the smallest index being the closest.